# I'd like to fit Laplace distribution to data in R using nls function, but I get an error: singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

Tags: r

Here is the example of the data:

```
  N22_v38_int N22_v45_int N24_v49_int x
1   0.1062731 0.009696623 0.002161193 1
2   0.1228782 0.012049179 0.002396424 2
3   0.1955720 0.014565391 0.004425299 3
4   0.3232472 0.018104453 0.007806757 4
5   0.4907749 0.022666367 0.011893910 5
6   0.6811808 0.027760162 0.016760269 6
```

Here is the code for fitting the Laplace to data:

```
res <- nls(peaks2[,1] ~ k / (2*b) * exp(-(x-mu)/ b), 
                         start=c(mu=15,b=0.5,k=1) , data = peaks2)
```

And the error message:

```
singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

Here is the example plot of the data:
[image]

Maybe it has something to do with the variance, because for the Laplace distribution the variance is 2b^2 .

Comment: Normally one uses maximum likelihood, not nls.  Google *laplace distribution R* to find a ready made function.

Comment: Your equation is overly parameterize your 3 parameters are not independent.  The algorithm having a issue trying to solve for b, mu, and K.